# Develop application using Storyboard or xib file

Tags: ios

I am beginner level ios developer.I want to know which is best practice to develop application using Storyboard or xib file? Why ?

I think xib file is easy to work.Also If I use Storyboard,it will be tough to add dynamic views.

Comment: The answer is, like many other topics of efficiency and style, "whatever makes you happy and doesn't cause problems"

Comment: I think you should follow storyboard it is a new one. Iy is easy also. After some time you will not face issues while adding dynamic views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storyboards are now apples recommendation. I have used storyboards to create the current app I'm working on and I love them. The ease of being able to see the entire flow of your app is fantastic, instead of having to open multiple xib files.

There is nothing stopping you from creating dynamic views when using a storyboard, you can add a blank view controller and have it linked to a code file that will create the entire view on viewDidAppear  or viewDidLoad.

You can also use "storyboardID" to create a shortcut so you can jump from one screen to any other screen without having a segue, comes in very handy sometimes.

Over all there is a bit of a learning curve to it, but the benefits especially towards debugging the flow of the app far out weighs the the learning curve, and using storyboards doesn't prevent you from doing anything else, as it can always be done in code later on as it would normally.

**Some links to help**

I have used this link to start of from scratch:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/Introduction/Introduction.html

This one looks a like it builds a bigger app using them, might be good:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: The only problem that I have with them is that they make my Mac screech to a halt when they get even a little complicated.  Plus they just beg for version control conflicts.

Comment: any guide available for storyboard using? Lot of books focused only on xib files only.

Comment: I added 2 links that should start you off. Yes slower macs will have an issue as they are quite heavy, I use SVN and even with xcode's terrible svn integration i've never had a conflict with the storyboard. Had many svn conflicts with a test image that just won't die, says its missing, thats because I deleted it!